# Premeasure on an algebra: $\sigma$-additive $\Rightarrow$ finite additive?

Tags: measure-theory

> > I have a very short question concerning a proof. If I have an algebra $\mathfrak{A}$ and a set function $\mu\colon\mathfrak{A}\to [0,\infty]$ for which I have to show that it is a premeasure on $\mathfrak{A}$, then I have (besides other things) to show, that $\mu$ is finite additive and $\sigma$-additive. Is it enough to show only the $\sigma$-additivity and does the finite additivitry follow from that?

For measures on $\sigma$-Algebras I know the answer: Then the $\sigma$-additivity implies finite additivity. But here I have no idea...

Comment: Do you perhaps recall how to prove the implication with $\sigma$-algebras, so that you could check whether it translates to this setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an algebra $\mathcal{A}$ and set measure $\mu : \mathcal{A} \to [0,\infty]$, the $\sigma$-additivity that you need to show is if $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty} \subset \mathcal{A}$ are disjoint such that $\cup_n A_n \in \mathcal{A}$, then $\mu(\cup_n A_n) = \sum_n \mu(A_n)$. Now, suppose that $A_1, ..., A_N$ are a finite collection of disjoint sets in $\mathcal{A}$. Since $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra, $\varnothing \in \mathcal{A}$. So, you can extend the finite set $A_1, ..., A_N$ to a disjoint countable subset by requiring $A_{N+k}=\varnothing$ for every $k \geq 1$. Now, if you have shown the $\sigma$-additivity then $$\mu(\cup_{n=1}^{N} A_n) = \mu(\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_n) = \sum_{n=1}^N \mu(A_n) + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mu(\varnothing)$$

Comment: For example I have disjoint $A_1,A_2$ in the algebra which union is in the algebra. Then in a first step, I can build $A_1\cup A_2\cup\emptyset$. This is in the algebra, because $A_1\uplus A_2$ is in the algebra and $\emptyset$ is in the algebra and the algebra is closed under the union of two elements. So in the nexe step, I create $A_1\cup A_2\emptyset\cup\emptyset$ and so on, getting a countable union $A_1\cup A_2\cup\emptyset\emptyset\cup\dots$ for which I can use the $\sigma$-additivity of $\mu$ (when I have shown it). Right?

Comment: You can take care of this all in one step. Notice that $\varnothing = \cup_{k=1}^{\infty}\varnothing$. So, $$\cup_{n=1}^N A_n = \left(\cup_{n=1}^N A_n \right) \cup \varnothing = \left(\cup_{n=1}^N A_n \right) \cup \left(\cup_{k=1}^{\infty}\varnothing \right)$$ Therefore, if $\cup_{n=1}^N A_n \in \mathcal{A}$, so is the countable union $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$ (where $A_{N+k} = \varnothing$) since these sets (the finite and countable unions) are, in fact, equal.